# Computing the inverse Laplace transform of this?

Tags: calculus, inverse, laplace-transform

What's the correct way to go about computing the Inverse Laplace transform of this?

$$\frac{-2s + 1}{(s^2+2s+5)}$$

I Completed the square on the bottom but what do you do now?

$$\frac{-2s + 1}{(s+1)^2 + 4}$$

Comment: The Maple command $$with(inttrans); invlaplace((-2*s+1)/(s^2+2*s+5), s, t); $$ ouputs $$1/2\,{{\rm e}^{-t}} \left( -4\,\cos \left( 2\,t \right) +3\,\sin
 \left( 2\,t \right)  \right) 
 .$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

the inverse Laplace Transforms of the two forms are:

$$\dfrac{a}{(s-b)^2 + a^2} = e^{bx} \sin ax$$

$$\dfrac{s-b}{(s-b)^2 + a^2} = e^{bx} \cos ax$$

Can you use those two forms and get a result of:

$$ e^{-t} \left(\dfrac{3}{2} \sin 2t - 2 \cos 2t\right)$$

Comment: Sweet, got it!!

Comment: @lorde: Excellent! Regards

Comment: Nice post and feedback! +1

Comment: My pleasure, and GOOD MORNING! Happy MTMOS Day: (Make The Most Of Sunday!)

Comment: That is a great acronym and we can say Make The Most Of Life (MTMOL)!